# [Nightwatch][selenium-server] Connection Refused! Is Selenium Server Started

Tags: nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I'm using nightwatch.js to test website, When running the google.js test which comes with Nightwatch I get the error back "Connection Refused is Selenium Server started?" and, well, it is. I started it.

The error I get is:
[image]

this is my nightwatch.json:

[image]

[image]

module ver:

```
node version : v14.16.0
```

[image]

Comment: Please check this post. This is very similar to yours - [Nightwatch - Connection Refused! Is Selenium Server Started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47079454/465053)

Answer (score -1):

This is Vishal here from the Nightwatch product team. We noticed that you are using Nightwatch version 0.9.21 whereas the latest version on the Nightwatch website is 2.2.2. Can you please try to upgrade to the latest version and let us know if the issue still persists?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).